# php add 2 or more post_type in $query

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

code original

```
if ( 'property' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $query;
    }
```

what i want to do but it doesn't work like that

```
 if ( 'property' != $post->post_type ) {
 if ( 'testimonial' != $post->post_type ) {
            return $query;
        }
```

How to add 2 or 3 post types ?

I add the full code so you can maybe understand why it doesn't work
and figure out how to make it work for different post types

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'filter_query_attachments_args' );

function filter_query_attachments_args( $query ) {
    // 1. Only users with access
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    // 2. No manipulation for admins.
    // After all they have access to all images.
    //if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        //return $query;
    //}

    // 3. No images, if the post_id is not provided
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    // 4. No images, if you are not the post type manager or author
    $post = get_post( (int) $_REQUEST['post_id'] );
    if ( ! $post instanceof \WP_Post ) {
        return $query;
    }

    // 5. You can also restrict the changes to your custom post type
    // Only filter for our custom post types
    if ( 'property' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $query;
    }
    
    // 5. You can also restrict the changes to your custom post type
    if ( 'testimonial' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $query;
    }
    
    // 8. Don't show private images
    $query['post_status'] = 'inherit';

    // 9. Filter to display only the images attached to the post
    $query['post_parent'] = $post->ID;

    // 10. Filter to display only the user uploaded image
    $query['editor'] = $current_user->ID;

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: See [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array).

Comment: By the way, your second snippet should work in you add another closing bracket, even if it's much uglier than using `in_array`.

Comment: I add the full code so you can maybe understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Your issue may be with `if ( ! $post instanceof \WP_Post )`. Here you are coercing`$post` to a boolean and negating it. Try `if ( ! ($post instanceof \WP_Post ))` instead, where you negate the truth of the `instanceof` evaluation instead. Or, for clarity, `if ($post instanceof \WP_Post === false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you want to be able to check two separate variables from the contents of post. You can put them in the same if block like this:

```
if ( 'property' != $post->post_type && 'testimonial' != $post->post_type ) {
         return $query;
    }
```

The two equality comparisons need to be separated by a logical `&&` operator.

Alternatively, you could nest the if blocks like this:

```
if ( 'property' != $post->post_type) {
    if ('testimonial' != $post->post_type ) {
         return $query;
    }
}
```

Depending on your implementation, you may want to use `!==` instead of `!=` to check not only for the value but also the type. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
for more information about operators in PHP.

Comment: thank you very much both methods work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array

```php
if (in_array($post->post_type, ['property', 'testimonial'])) {}
```

Comment: I add the full code so you can maybe understand why it doesn't work